# Undefined error when using jQuery find() method

Tags: jquery

I want to grab a value using the code below every time when it changed by the loop, but I'm getting an error "Undefined".

```
 @foreach($items as $item)
    <li class="list-group-item ourItem" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">{{$item->item}}</li>
    <input type="hidden" id="itemId"  value="{{$item->id}}"/>
 @endforeach

$(document).on("click", ".ourItem", function(event) {
  var text = $(this).text();
  var id = $(this).find('#itemId').val();
  $('#addItem').val(text);
  $('#modelTile').text("Edit Item");
  $('#delete').show('400');
  $('#saveChange').show('400');
  $('#addItemBtn').hide("400");
  $('#id').val(id);
  console.log(id);
});
```

Comment: Find only finds descendants. itemId is not a child of ourItem.

Comment: First of all, you are re-using the `itemId` for multiple input elements. IDs must be unique within the document. Also, it is not clear where are the other elements are, such as `#addItem` and `#modelTile`. Where are they in your markup? p/s: Always post the **rendered** version of your markup.

Comment: <div class="modal-header">
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
   <h4 class="modal-title" id="modelTile" >ADD ITEM</h4>
  </div>

Comment: <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete" data-dismiss="modal" style="display: none">Delete</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="saveChange" style="display: none">Save changes</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addItemBtn" data-dismiss="modal">Add Item</button>
                    </div>

Comment: Here is the other element

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If i understand the general logic correctly, this should work.
Try this

```
var id = $(this).next('input').val();
```

Instead of this

```
var id = $(this).find('#itemId').val();
```

Comment: Glad to help, find() works for child elements, so you can use next() or siblings() in your situation

Comment: Despite this solution works, I suggest mentioning that the markup (HTML) should be fixed in order to avoid having multiple nodes with the same `itemId` **id** (that perhaps with this solution is no longer needed)

Comment: I am highly grateful to you. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the "error" that `id` is `undefined` because jQuery's `find()` fails to find the element.

This happens because as per [AtheistP3ace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1240676/atheistp3ace)'s comment

*`find()` only finds descendants. itemId is not a child of ourItem.*

Said that...

---

First, let the `<input>` node be a child of the `<li>` element.

```
@foreach($items as $item)
    <li class="list-group-item ourItem" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">{{$item->item}}
        <input type="hidden" class="item-value"  value="{{$item->id}}"/>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Then **you cannot have many nodes with the same HTML id**, instead just give to `<input>` nodes a class with the purpose to find them when the parent element is clicked.

In the snippet above the class is `item-value` while the **id** is removed.

---

Finally the JavaScript part is fixed with

`var id = $(this).find('.item-value').val();`

The whole JS becomes:

```
$(document).on("click", ".ourItem", function(event) {
  var text = $(this).text();
  var id = $(this).find('.item-value').val(); // <--- fixed here
  $('#addItem').val(text);
  $('#modelTile').text("Edit Item");
  $('#delete').show('400');
  $('#saveChange').show('400');
  $('#addItemBtn').hide("400");
  $('#id').val(id);
  console.log(id);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
var id = $(this).find('#itemId').val();
```

for

```
var id = $('#itemId').val();
```